# How would I make it rain as hard as possible

Tags: science-based, climate, weather

I want to create a world where it rains *super hard* to the point where it could kill someone but I also want it so that a person could live there without any sort of specialized equipment (Like a suit).

If I reduce the atmosphere then people wont be able to breathe and if I increase the gravity so that the rain falls faster then you wouldn’t be able to stand (plus that would also increase atmospheric pressure).

Edit: *super hard* (as in fast)

Comment: For reference, on Earth, [BBC Science Focus Magazine](https://www.sciencefocus.com/planet-earth/how-fast-does-rain-fall/) says that *"the [terminal velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity) of a raindrop depends on its size. The water droplets in clouds are only around 20 microns across and fall at only 1cm per second or so. This is normally balanced by updraughts, so the cloud stays in the sky. The droplets in a light shower are 100 times larger and fall at 6.5m/s or about 22.5km/h (14mph). The largest possible raindrops are 5mm across and hit the ground at 32km/h (20mph)."*

Comment: I don't understand the apparent contradiction in your question : You tell your goal is to kill people with rain, but at the same time you want to have them live there without protection... What do you mean exactly? That in sunny or equivalent circumstances they can live?

Comment: @Tortliena Well I’m writing a story so I can’t kill off characters the second they enter this place. I don’t want it to rain constantly so I want them to live when it’s not raining.

Comment: @AlexP
That’s a good idea. I’ll change the droplet size but maybe not too big because then it just wouldn’t look right.

Comment: there is no combination of circumstance in which a human could survive in and rain will cause serous trauma. terminal velocity, surface tension,  how rain has to form, and biological material strength are not that flexible. sometimes the only answer is handwavium

Comment: The bigger a drop gets, the more friction it experiences in the atmosphere, which breaks it apart. Water's cohesion is very weak. Even volume isn't an option because atmosphere can only hold so much water vapor. Whatever solution you end up with, so long as you use the [tag:science-based] tag, it won't be with liquid water.

Comment: Regular meteor showers, maybe? Make the meteors ice?

Comment: Here on the northern east coast of Australia it sometimes rains so long and hard and fast, it's hard to get a breath of air if you're caught in it. It's like air is replaced by wind and water. Old and weak as I am, I have thought that if I fell over I might drown in a puddle. On the east coast we have what are called rain bombs, where an east coast low (weather system) is fed by continuous evaporation from the sea. It rains hard for days. 900 mm overnight is not unusual. And that's reality.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Ice

To 'kill' someone with fast-moving water, you'd need something like a water-jet cutter to kill them by physical trauma. Sure, snow sure isn't going to kill someone that easily, but a half-meter-wide ice boulder falling out of the sky sure will.

Other than suffocating people with flooding from the torrential downpours, then I doubt you can kill people with **rain**.

> [Hail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hail) forms in strong thunderstorm clouds, particularly those with
> intense updrafts, high liquid-water content, great vertical extent,
> large water droplets, and where a good portion of the cloud layer is
> below freezing.

If you're going to have a fictional planet, then one with little tilt and large oceans could help to form planet-wide storms. It would probably help for it to be rather cold (on the far side of the habitable zone, or with less of a heat-trapping atmosphere).

> Hail forms as precipitation in cumulonimbus clouds. As the droplets
> rise and the temperature goes below freezing, they become supercooled
> water and will freeze on contact with condensation nuclei.
>
> A cross-section through a large hailstone shows an onion-like
> structure. This means that the hailstone is made of thick and
> translucent layers, alternating with layers that are thin, white and
> opaque.
>
> Former theory suggested that hailstones were subjected to
> multiple descents and ascents, falling into a zone of humidity and
> refreezing as they were uplifted.

So you'd want a planet with perpetual cold thunderstorms. Quite the foreboding place!

Comment: This is a thoughtful and detailed answer! One piece of advice: when quoting other sources, it's good to name them.

Comment: @Tom Thanks! **happy Neko noises*** Next time I will, and for the OP, its wikipedia.

Comment: Nothing's stopping you from editing your question. It's even encouraged.

Comment: From the same Wikipedia article: the largest officially measured hailstone had 7.9 in (20 cm) diameter. Much smaller ice pieces falling from the sky can kill you, especially if there's a shower of them. Of note: the weather doesn't have to be cold. In temperate zones, hailstorms are most common in the summer.

Comment: I've added a word-link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hail . Feel free to undo my change if you don't like it.

Comment: A few years ago, in December, a hailstorm hit Garland Texas where some of the hail (softball size or larger) penetrated the ground (hard clay) 3-4 inches. Any one of those could have killed someone.

Answer (score 5):

### there is no combination of circumstance in which a human could survive in and rain will cause serous trauma. terminal velocity, surface tension, how rain has to form, and biological material strength are not that flexible.

if you increase the gravity or make the air thicker, rain gets broken up even more by air resistance, so you only get smaller droplets.

if you make the atmosphere thinner to reduce air resistance, then it can't move enough water to make significant enough amounts of rain to get large droplets. at even at the bare minimum atmosphere low density pure oxygen, water still breaks up too fast to reach significantly higher kinetic energy.

Sometimes the only answer is handwavium